# Magento 2 - How to create language package (run command line) by PHP?

Tags: magento2, language, internationalization

I created a language package by using this command:

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o "app/default.csv" -m
```

and using

```
php bin/magento i18n:pack --mode=merge -d "app/default.csv" "xx_YY"
```

to distribute to each module.
But I want use PHP code to simulate both command line calls. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use the [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [`system`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) functions.
But if you don't want to do that...
The commands map to some php class and method so you should be able to simulate the code.
For example the `i18n:collect-phrases` maps to [`\Magento\Setup\Console\Command\I18nCollectPhrasesCommand::execute`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/I18nCollectPhrasesCommand.php#L62).

Try to replicate in your code the behavior from that method. Do the same for `i18n:pack`.  This one maps to `Magento\Setup\Console\Command\I18nPackCommand::execute`.

If you want to do it in your own class, try adding this code to your method:

Add this at the top of the file

```
use Magento\Setup\Module\I18n\ServiceLocator;
```

then in your method add this:

```
$directory = 'Add here directory of file to parse. leave empty for all'
$generator = ServiceLocator::getDictionaryGenerator();
$generator->generate(
    $directory,
    "app/default.csv",
    1 //if you specified a certain directory to parse set this to 1.
);
```

I haven't tested the code, so you might need to debug things.

Comment: yes, I saw these class. But I don't know how to call it in my controller or block. Sorry because I'm a newbie in Magento.

Comment: See my edit to the answer.

Comment: Oh, yay. Thanks so much, it's done. Even though it slow a little bit with browser.